# Why does mongodb install require removal of VirtualBox and php-curl?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, mongodb, linuxmint

I was about to install mongodb on Linux Mint 19.1 (Tessa) via .deb file but when I checked the packages to be removed, I found this:

[image: Screenshot of changes required]

> To install the following changes are required:
>   To be removed: curl
>   To be removed: libcurl4
>   To be removed: php-curl
>   To be removed: php7.2-curl
>   To be removed: virtualbox-6.0
>   To be installed: libcurl3

Many packages I need are going to be deleted, is this true or is it a bug?
Can I just ignore this and install mongodb?

Comment: Where did you get a mongodb deb? It is probably the wrong one.

Comment: It looks like you are installing the package for Ubuntu 16.04, which requires `libcurl3` (which conflicts with `libcurl4`). For Linux Mint 19 you should instead be installing the [package for Ubuntu 18.04](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#create-a-list-file-for-mongodb) which uses `libcurl4`.

Comment: @Stennie Thank you very much, you are so right! The right version has no problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are installing the MongoDB package for Ubuntu 16.04, which requires `libcurl3` (and [conflicts with `libcurl4`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/curl/+bug/1754686)).

For Linux Mint 19.1 you should instead be installing the [MongoDB package for Ubuntu 18.04](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#create-a-list-file-for-mongodb) which uses `libcurl4`.